# View questions by comments

Tags: feature-request, support, comments, search

I can see my comments by clicking **activity -> comments**. However, I never have only one comment per question. If I have commented a lot on a question looking over all questions that I have seen becomes difficult.

I want to treat all comments on a question as being the same and therefore see only one, representative, comment to draw a question. That is, if I had 100 comments per question, I want to see only one.

Is this possible?

Comment: Simple fix: don't enter flames.

Comment: It is ideal if people could understand you from the single note. However, I always have trouble with this.

Comment: I really don't think this is necessary. First of all, that many comments should not be necessary. And if a situation has been clarified, ideally the comments should be removed. In fact, some of your recent comments [here for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932663/calculate-time-using-formula-speed-distance-time/18932723#comment27963257_18932723) were not really necessary, nor should they be so drawn out. The whole comment thread there can go. Just try to keep them to a minimum, clean up when you can, and as @Mat says, don't enter flames.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For stuff like this (not often used/needed), use [the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) or [the Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

- The Data Explorer (SEDE) is easy to use but the data may be a few days old.
- The API is up to the minute but a bit more involved, and subject to quota restrictions.

Here is [a SEDE query that groups your comments by post](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/138607/users-comments-grouped-by-post?UserId=1083704), to get you started.

Comment: Here is more appropriate partitioning of comments by questions, http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/revision/138658/170355/comment-partition-by-question